# Extracting conditional values from json file

Tags: python, json, file

I have created the following code to parse through a JSON file and extract certain values that meet a certain condition and place them into a text file. My code runs with no errors, and to me looks ok. However, when I opened the text file it is blank.

```
def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):

ifile = open(ifile_name, 'r')
ofile = open(ofile_name, "w")
json_decode=json.load(ifile)
result = []
for i in json_decode['Culture']['Movies']:
    for k in json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i]:
        if "Oscars" in json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i][k] == 0 and "Genre" in json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i][k] == Comedy:
            data = "Actors" in json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i][k]
            print data
            result.append(data)

for j in result:
    ofile.write(j+'\n')
```

The JSON file is the following

```
{
    "Culture": {
        "Movies": {
            "2015": {
                "Birdman": {
                    "Genre": "Comedy",
                    "Director": "Alejandro Inarritu",
                    "Oscars": 9,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Michael Keaton",
                        "Enma Stone",
                        "Edward Norton",
                        "Naomi Watts"
                    ]
                },
                "The Imitation Game": {
                    "Genre": "Drama",
                    "Director": "Morten Tyldum",
                    "Oscars": 8,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Benedict Cumberbatch",
                        "Keira Knightley",
                        "Matthew Goode"
                    ]
                },
                "Magic in the Moonlight": {
                    "Genre": "Comedy",
                    "Director": "Woody Allen",
                    "Oscars": 0,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Enma Stone",
                        "Colin Firth",
                        "Marcia Harden"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "2014": {
                "Gravity": {
                    "Genre": "Drama",
                    "Director": "Alfonso Cuaron",
                    "Oscars": 10,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Sandra Bullock",
                        "George Clooney",
                        "Ed Harris",
                        "Paul Sharma"
                    ]
                },
                "Blue Jasmine": {
                    "Genre": "Comedy",
                    "Director": "Woody Allen",
                    "Oscars": 1,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Cate Blanchett",
                        "Sally Hawkins",
                        "Alec Baldwin"
                    ]
                },
                "Blended": {
                    "Genre": "Romance",
                    "Director": "Frank Coraci",
                    "Oscars": 0,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Adam Sandler",
                        "Drew Barrymore",
                        "Jack Giarraputo"
                    ]
                },
                "Ocho Apellidos Vascos": {
                    "Genre": "Comedy",
                    "Director": "Emilio Lazaro",
                    "Oscars": 0,
                    "Actors": [
                        "Dani Rovira",
                        "Clara Lago",
                        "Karra Elejalde",
                        "Carmen Machi"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "Books": {
            "2015": {
                "Go Set a Watchman": {
                    "Genre": "Fiction",
                    "Author": "Harper Lee",
                    "Pages": 278
                },
                "The Girl on the Train": {
                    "Genre": "Thriller",
                    "Author": "Paula Hawkins",
                    "Pages": 320
                }
            },
            "2014": {
                "El Barco de los Ninos": {
                    "Genre": "Children",
                    "Author": "Mario Llosa",
                    "Pages": 96
                },
                "Sapiens": {
                    "Genre": "History",
                    "Author": "Yuval Harari",
                    "Pages": 464
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the names of ACTORS who played in a COMEDY movie that won 0 OSCARS. From looking at my code it looks right to me, hopefully someone can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the json file you gave had a missing bracket in the end. Secondly, this is the working code. You were wrong in the if condition and the data initialization.

```
import json
def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):
  ifile = open(ifile_name, 'r')
  ofile = open(ofile_name, "w")
  json_decode=json.load(ifile)
  result = []
  for i in json_decode['Culture']['Movies']:
      for k in json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i]:
          if json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i][k]['Oscars'] == 0  and  json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i][k]['Genre'] == "Comedy":
            data = json_decode['Culture']['Movies'][i][k]['Actors']
            print data
            result.append(data)

for j in result:
    ofile.write(str(j)+str('\n'))

my_main('movies.json','o.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you Amar I see my error now, at least I know I was not too far off.